# Text align works for one tag but not for another?

Tags: html, css

im making a simple webpage. 
i use the style format 
i create one and it text aligns that but not the other. im sure its something simple but what am i doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
p {
 color: Black;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 } 

 body {
 background-color: lightgray;
}

f { color: green; 
text-align: center;
}

</style>

<body>

<p>hello world!</p>
<f>hello again world</f>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the `<f>` tag supposed to be? Anyway, the text **is** centered it's just that `<f>` doesn't span the whole width of the page like `<p>` does.

Comment: it it another 'p' tag ? there is no 'f' tag

Answer (score 2):

An f tag is not a standard tag, if you invent your own tag it is not going to have a display rule so make it block.

Try

```
f { color: green; 
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: *it is not going to have a display* it will have a display rule like any element with an default value equal to *inline*

Comment: @JacksonODonnel or you could add a dot before f  (.f) to make it into a class, this way <div class="f">hello</div>  (e.g.) would be formatted in line with the f class.